# Changing the font of dirtree

Tags: fonts, dirtree

How can I change the font of `dirtree` to the roman family (i.e. `\textrm{}`)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{dirtree}

\begin{document}

\dirtree{%
.1 Hardware.
.2 Devices.
.3 Tablets.
.4 Operating-System: Android.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{dirtree}

\begin{document}
\dirtree{%
.1 Hardware.
.2 Devices.
.3 Tablets.
.4 Operating-System: Android.
}


\renewcommand\DTstyle{\rmfamily}
\dirtree{%
.1 Hardware.
.2 Devices.
.3 Tablets.
.4 Operating-System: Android.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]